# Oriented graph VS directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Alright, while the definitions are stated in my lecure notes, textbooks and wiki, I'll be honest, it just explodes my mind with what seems like word sorcery.

**Definition**

> *A directed graph is called an oriented graph if it is the orientation of an undirected graph.*

**What are the distinctions between Oriented graphs and digraphs?**

> 1. An oriented graph is a directed graph with orientation?
> 2. But isn't "directed" already standing for being "oriented?" I just don't get it, "oriented" and "directed" seems like an interchange between "PC" and "laptop", it seems like it's just another way of saying it.
> 3. How can something be directed but not oriented and vice versa?
> 4. Where can you find a casual explanation between the distinction?

Comment: That's a badly worded definition. Where did you find it specifically?

Comment: But to answer the question, I know of no practical difference between an "oriented" graph and a "directed" graph.

Comment: That's the definition found in mathworld http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrientedGraph.html I don't know if it is widely used but I found it there.

Comment: @Gamamal: I would say that defintion is not widely used. It looks perhaps like the writer of that web page plucked it ouf of some paper cited there, without awareness of the special nature of the terminology in that paper.

Comment: hi, I found it on wikipedia for Orientation(graph theory). Well, I can't think of a difference too, but it's implied that there is...apparently. It seems to indicate that all oriented graphs are directed, but all directed graphs are not necessarily oriented...which is the reason that gets me baffled. I'm just wondering who came up with very confounding names to these definitions, I feel very uncomfortable with it...

Answer (score 13):

An oriented graph is an undirected graph with orientation.

Think of it this way, every oriented graph is a directed graph, but not viceversa.

Every oriented graph can be obtained by taking a simple undirected graph and assigning a direction to every edge. This is not true for every directed graph.

Basically directed graphs can have an arrow going from $A$ to $B$ and an arrow going from $B$ to $A$. oriented graphs can have at most one arrow between any two vertices $A$ and $B$.

[image]

This image shows a directed graph which is not an oriented graph, it is not oriented because it contains an arrow from $(2,2)$ to $(1,1)$ and an arrow going from $(1,1)$ to $(2,2)$. (Image taken from wikimedia commons)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but hang on....are you saying the difference is "having TWO arrowed edges or ONE arrowed edge" between vertices?? So if I take away one of the edges between 11 and 22 in the above diagram, it becomes oriented?

Comment: Yes, if you do that then you get an oriented graph. The difference is oriented graphs cannot have two arrows between two vertices.

Comment: Oh....alright, so that's all there is to it then? thanks!

Comment: yes, that is the only difference. the orientable graphs are all the directed graphs except the ones with double arrows.

Comment: Let me add that that oriented graphs are used to study undirected graphs. It is convenient to view the orientations of edges as an external structure that can be modified without changing the underlying graph. Oriented graphs are central to the FKT algorithm, k-Pfaffian graphs, ...

Answer (score 6):

Shortly

> *"an oriented graph is a digraph without multiple edges or loops"*

more can be found in Diestel, Graph Theory book (p.28 in 2005 Electronic edition).