# Difference between Oriented Graph and Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAG)

Tags: graph-theory, definition

**Definition of [Oriented Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1286696/407302):**

> Basically directed graphs can have an arrow going from $A$ to $B$ and
> an arrow going from $B$ to $A$. Oriented graphs can have at most one
> arrow between any two vertices $A$ and $B$.

**Definition of [Directed Acylic Graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)**

> In mathematics, particularly graph theory, and computer science, a
> directed acyclic graph (DAG) is a finite directed graph with **no
> directed cycles**.

An edge from $A$ to $B$ and another from $B$ to $A$ is a cycle right ?

Then if Oriented graphs already do not have such a cycle then how are they different from DAGs ? Unless of course DAGs **need some other constraint satisfied ?** In that case what are they ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$ would be a directed cycle, but they can be longer. For instance, consider a graph with three vertices $A,B,C$ and edges $A\rightarrow B, B\rightarrow C, C\rightarrow A$. Such a graph is oriented, but it is not a DAG, because there is a cycle.