# Are Oriented Graphs Related to Oriented Matroids?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, matroids, reference-works

My professor said that oriented matroids make it easier to investigate things such as connectivity. Recall that an oriented graph is a digraph without multiple edges or loops. Now

**Are oriented graphs related to oriented matroids? Or does the term orientation here mean something totally distinct things?**

1. Where can you find analysis on the relationship between the two concepts with orientations in graphs and matroids?
2. What are good introductory material on matroid with background in graph theory?

Comment: I don't know about any other part of the question, but I think Oxley's *Matroid Theory* is a pretty standard textbook. There's also helpful info on his webpage (like an introductory article *What is a matroid?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as undirected graphs give rise to so called `graphic matroids,` directed graphs give rise to `graphic oriented matroids.` Here's the set up:

A directed graph $G = (V,E,\mathcal{O})$ (possibly with loops and/or multiple edges) with orientation $\mathcal{O}$ has associated to it an oriented matroid called the graphic oriented matroid of $M(G)$ of $G$. The oriented matroid $M(G)$ is a representable oriented matroid represented by the signed vertex-edge incidence matrix $N(G)$ of $G$ defined as follows. $N(G)$ has rows (respectively, columns) indexed by the vertices (resp. edges) of $G$. The entry $(v,e)$ of $N$ is given by
$$ N(v,e) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if $v$ is the head of the edge $e$},\\
-1 &\text{ if $v$ is the tail of the edge $e$},\\
0 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

While all graphic matroids are [orientable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_matroid#Orientability), this is not the case for general matroids. For example, the Fano matroid is not orientable. Oxley's [Matroid Theory](https://books.google.at/books?id=puKta1Hdz-8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=oxley%20matroid%20theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmjKGbt6HQAhVCvBoKHbjvDzwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=oxley%20matroid%20theory&f=false) provides a brief discussion on orientable matroids and is easily accessible for anyone with a basic background in graph theory. The standard text for oriented matroids, [Oriented Matroids](https://books.google.at/books?id=k2an6eBxn3kC&pg=PA323&lpg=PA323&dq=matroids%20weak%20map&source=bl&ots=Y3C7-v_8LT&sig=hT_iq85oyjxoVoVBOrl6tGFzpYg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZoufK-57QAhUCChoKHX17BuoQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=orientable&f=false), also discusses the interplay between oriented matroids and (non)orientable matroids.