# On terms "Orientation" & "Oriented" in different mathematical areas?

Tags: reference-request, orientation, reference-works

The goal of this question is to help to deal with different meanings of the words such as *"orientation"* and *"oriented"* in different mathematical areas.

**Are different oriented concepts somehow related to each other in different mathematical areas?**

> 1. Oriented matroids (Matroid Theory)
> 2. Oriented graphs (Graph Theory)
> 3. Orientation (Topology, Global Analysis)
> 4. Other areas?

Answer (score 1):

I outline some graph theory and matroids where orientation occurs in the terms such as oriented matroids and oriented graphs.

**Distinctions**

> 1. [Are Oriented Graphs Related to Oriented Matroids?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812773/are-oriented-graphs-related-to-oriented-matroids)
>
> > 1.1. [Intuitive explation for oriented matroids?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184790/intuitive-explation-for-oriented-matroids) (with oriented matroids and digraphs question)
> >
> > 1.2. What is the analogous duality theorem between the cuts and cycles related to Matroids?